# I want to increase my variables but it shows only the string. (output: $bgcolor1)

Tags: php

I have a couple of variables, and after I increase the numbers, it only shows $bgcolor1. But I want that it write out this: bgcolor='#0066CC'.
I just cannot figure out the solution. 
Hope someone can help me.
Thanks!

```
$bgcolor1 = "bgcolor='#0066CC'";
$bgcolor2 = "bgcolor='#FF0000'";
$bgcolor3 = "bgcolor='#00FF00'";


for ($c = 1; $c <=5; $c++){

    print "<table border='1' ".'$bgcolor'.$c.">";

}
```

Comment: please start using css

Comment: What exactly is the result of concatenating hex color and a number?

Comment: Also read up on [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$bgcolor1 = "bgcolor='#0066CC'";
$bgcolor2 = "bgcolor='#FF0000'";
$bgcolor3 = "bgcolor='#00FF00'";

for ($c = 1; $c <=5; $c++){
    print "<table border='1' ".${"bgcolor".$c}.">";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$bgcolor1 = "bgcolor='#0066CC'";
$bgcolor2 = "bgcolor='#FF0000'";
$bgcolor3 = "bgcolor='#00FF00'";


for ($c = 1; $c <=5; $c++){
    $bgcolor = "{$bgcolor}{$c}";
     print "<table border='1' ". $bgcolor . ">";
}
```

Comment: Try this: `explanation text...`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the colors in an array, then looping over the array and printing them out.

```
$bgcolors = array("bgcolor='#0066CC'", "bgcolor='#FF0000'", "bgcolor='#00FF00'");

for ($c = 0; $c < 3; $c++){

    print "<table border='1' " . $bgcolors[$c] . ">";

}
```